# Точное повторное выполнение цикла через определенные промежуток времени после его начала. С#

Tags: c#

Добрый день, есть цикл:

```
while('условие') 
{
   // код
}
```

Требуется чтобы новая итерация цикла происходила через одну секунду после его начала.

```
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

не подходит, т.к. засыпать он будет на секунду уже после окончания цикла, и время будет 1000+время выполнения цикла

Comment: а если цикл не успеет выполниться за одну секунду?

Comment: чем не устраивает обычный таймер?

Comment: Будем считать, что успеет.

Comment: обычный таймер плюс переменная флаг того, что задача выполняется и если задача не успела, то реагировать иначе же просто стартовать задачу.

Comment: Попробуйте смотреть системное время в начале цикла и сверяться с ним периодически в теле цикла. Если разница достигла 1 секунды - `goto` в начало цикла.

Comment: Стыдно признавать, но обычные таймеры как то вылетели из головы. :-( Сижу тут изобрести их пытаюсь... :-))))

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно так:

```
while (условие)
{
    var oneSecond = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // ожидание начинается тут в фоне
    // тело цикла
    await oneSecond; // а здесь мы заканчиваем начатое ожидание
}
```

Comment: А если тело цикла будет выполняться больше 1 секунды?

Comment: @Anatol: Тут уж ничего не поделать, await отработает мгновенно, но общее время выполнения будет таким, сколько выполнялась итерация.

Comment: Используй Stopwatch и вычитай из секунды затраченное время на метод

Comment: @Serginio: И чем ваше предложение лучше метода из ответа? Технически оно явно сложнее и менее читабельно (попробуйте сами реализовать), а какие выгоды оно приносит?

Comment: @ VladD прошу прощения не всмотрелся.

Comment: @Anatol Можешь цикл выделить в отдельную задачу и использовать Task.WaitAny(ТвойЦикл,oneSecond ) если цикл закончился раньше вызываешь await oneSecond , если oneSecond  закончился раньше делаешь свои движения и дожидаешься выполнения цикла

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю еще одно решение по мотивам [Asynchronously wait for Task to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)
Сделаем тело цикла Задачей

```
while(true)
{
var task = SomeOperationAsync(); // Выполняем тело цикла
var oneSecond = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // ожидание начинается тут в фоне



if (await Task.WhenAny(task, oneSecond ) == task) {
    // задача выпонилась раньше 1 секунды
  await oneSecond; // а здесь мы заканчиваем начатое ожидание

} else { 
    // прошла секунда, а задача ещё  не выпонилась
// делаем телодвижения и дожидаемся окончания задачи
await task;
 // или можно запустить новую без ожидания старой

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь `Stopwatch`

А еще вы можете запускать новые потоки....