# Скачивание файлов C#

Tags: c#

*WebClient* дает возможность скачивания файла используя *Uri* в **синхронном** и **асинхронном** режиме. 
Но, возникла необходимость ограничения скорости скачивания файла. 
Средствами *WebClient* я не нашел способа решения этой проблемы. 
Есть одна [ссылка](http://www.csharpcoderr.com/2012/08/download-a-file.html), где показывают, как достать данные о загрузке, но это все равно не то. 
Окей, не нашел и ладно - подумал я. И решил поискать другой способ скачивания файла и... **не нашел**. 
А какие способы скачивания файлов средствами C#, **кроме** использования *WebClient*, знаете вы? Поделитесь, пожалуйста. 
И если вы знаете, как ограничить скорость скачивания файлов - буду тоже рад видеть.

Comment: Можно использовать этот аналог выполнение метода через определенное время http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583438/%d0%a2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b3/583827#583827

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простое решение, приостанавливающее загрузку, если превышена скорость.

```
public static async Task DownloadUriWithThrottling(Uri uri, string path, double speedKbps)
{
    var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
    using (var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync())
    using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    using (var outfile = File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        long totalDownloaded = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[0x10000];
        while (true)
        {
            var actuallyRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (actuallyRead == 0) // end of stream
                return;
            await outfile.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, actuallyRead);
            totalDownloaded += actuallyRead;

            // recalc speed and wait
            var expectedTime = totalDownloaded / 1024.0 / speedKbps;
            var actualTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;
            if (expectedTime > actualTime)
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expectedTime - actualTime));
        }
    }
}
```

(Не тестировал.)

Возможно, при маленьких скоростях имеет смысл брать размер буфера не с потолка, а руководствуясь какой-то логикой.

Comment: На маленьких скоростях при быстром соединении надо делать фиксированную задержку, а управлять размером буфера. Т.е. формула выворачивается: `expectedDownloaded = totalTime / 1024.0 / speedKbps`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Угу, для этого случая буфер нужен из соображений «на секунду скачки» или типа того.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Но это уже fine tuning. Посмотрим, подойдёт ли эта логика ТС. (А я ушёл на обед.)

Comment: @VladD, подойдет более чем, спасибо. Приятного аппетита.

Comment: @Ep1demic: Спасибо!

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А может, в этом случае просто уменьшить размер буфера, скажем, до 4К? Чем лучше фиксированная задержка?

Comment: @VladD более гладкая производная сигнала управления, меньше колебания загрузки сети.

Answer (score 2):

Протокол TCP работает таким образом, что данные по сети будут передаваться с той же скоростью, с какой вы считываете их из сетевого потока.

Поэтому вам надо использовать методы, которые возвращают поток (Stream) и ограничить свою скорость чтения данных оттуда. Например, через `Thread.Sleep` в синхронном коде или через `Task.Delay` в асинхронном.

Comment: Угу, как раз такой пример и набросал.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456717/2003555) такое решение c испльзованием задержки при превышении допустимой скорости

```
public class ThrottledStream : Stream
{
    #region Properties

    private int maxBytesPerSecond;
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of Bytes that are allowed per second
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxBytesPerSecond
    {
        get { return maxBytesPerSecond; }
        set 
        {
            if (value < 1)
                throw new ArgumentException("MaxBytesPerSecond has to be >0");

            maxBytesPerSecond = value; 
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region Private Members

    private int processed;
    System.Timers.Timer resettimer;
    AutoResetEvent wh = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    private Stream parent;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Stream with Databandwith cap
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parentStream"></param>
    /// <param name="maxBytesPerSecond"></param>
    public ThrottledStream(Stream parentStream, int maxBytesPerSecond=int.MaxValue) 
    {
        MaxBytesPerSecond = maxBytesPerSecond;
        parent = parentStream;
        processed = 0;
        resettimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        resettimer.Interval = 1000;
        resettimer.Elapsed += resettimer_Elapsed;
        resettimer.Start();         
    }

    protected void Throttle(int bytes)
    {
        try
        {
            processed += bytes;
            if (processed >= maxBytesPerSecond)
                wh.WaitOne();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    private void resettimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        processed = 0;
        wh.Set();
    }

    #region Stream-Overrides

    public override void Close()
    {
        resettimer.Stop();
        resettimer.Close();
        base.Close();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        resettimer.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return parent.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return parent.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return parent.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        parent.Flush();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return parent.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return parent.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            parent.Position = value;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        Throttle(count);
        return parent.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return parent.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        parent.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        Throttle(count);
        parent.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Comment: Довольно интересное решение, но здесь отсутствует прямая загрузка по Uri (нужно играться со stream'ом). Подождем более красивого решения ;)

Comment: @Ep1demic а красивого и не будет. Встроенной функциональности у WebClient нет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну почему же не будет?) Вот выше пример более короткий, лаконичный и с передаваемым параметром Uri, а не stream

Comment: @Ep1demic мда...

Comment: @Ep1demic а ничего, что там внутри тоже поток используется?

Comment: @Ep1demic вы что, не способны сами сделать метод, который последовательно вызывает два других?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, способен, уже и начинал делать, просто VladD набросал метод быстрее меня. 
Я вижу, что там так же используется поток, но ответ то все равно в разы короче этого и более простой для чтения. Я ведь не утверждаю, что это решение плохое, просто говорю что тот лучше.