# Есть ли способ управлять загрузкой ответа WebResponse?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Здравствуйте!
Необходимо асинхронно получать ответ с сервера и, при этом, знать на каком этапе находится этот самый ответ, то есть сколько в данный момент загружено байт. Что бы, например, в любой момент можно было бы ограничить скорость загрузки или прервать получение ответа или просто следить за прогрессом загрузки ответа и тп. Возможно ли это вообще? 
Нашел в интернете пример с wpf, но в консольной версии такое повторить не удается. В принципе, мне без разницы что использовать - webclent или webresponse или другие средства если они есть. 
Если кто-то сталкивался когда-то с такой задачей - отзовитесь.

Comment: Было тут недавно, сейчас поищу.

Comment: Вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588386/10105 (судя по всему, дубликат).

Comment: Окей. 
И еще один вопрос по теории. Простой, думаю, но мне для понимания происходящего нужен.
Например, в общем случае, есть ссылка на файл: hhtp://example.com/file.rar. Моя задача это файл скачать. Создаю запрос (get). Создаю переменную типа webresponse. Дак вот какой механизм работы .Net дальше? Создается область в памяти (в куче) и туда записывается тот самый файл? И только потом с помощью класса strem я сохраняю его на диск к себе? А пока я не применил методы из класса stream мой файл болтается в оперативной памяти в куче? Все верно?

Comment: Сейчас посмотрю, спасибо

Comment: Ну, вы получаете HTTP-ответ (как объект, реально он ещё не загружен), получаете Stream на его контент, и просто копируете куски из этого стрима куда хотите.

Comment: А я думал ответ (там ведь тело сообщения) - это и есть уже загруженный в оперативную память файл (в этом случае) или страница, нет? То есть если ссылка будет на файл весить 500 мегабайт, то нам не придется ждать, чтобы загрузились все данные файла получая ответ от сервера? То есть строчка WebResponse response= (WebResponse)request.GetResponse(); еще не значит, что в память записалось все те 500 мегабайт? В любом случае нужно будет соединение чтобы потом их тянуть с помощью stream?

Comment: Именно так. Этот response — это по сути только HTTP-заголовок. Ответ нужно вычитывать из стрима, и можно его, например, не дочитать до конца, если не нужно.

Comment: ммм, все понятно. Я думал, что все уже и так находится в ответе. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста! То есть вопрос тогда закрыт?

Comment: Ну предварительно - да, я пока просто разбираюсь с тем кодом, который в ответе вы указали

Comment: А еще вопрос про буфер. Он как-то осознанно выбирается? Почему в примере его размерность 0х10000? Размерность как то зависит от свойства ContentLenght?

Comment: Это сложный вопрос. У меня взят от фонаря. SO предлагает какие-то константы, поищите. @PavelMayorov вообще предлагал делать задержку при помощи динамической подгонки размера буфера (классная идея, кстати).

Comment: Я, кстати, примерно, понял о чем речь, видел где-то на msdn. Благодарю